# Adding combobox to Ribbon Control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a WPF Application with a `Ribbon Control`. I want to add a `ComboBox`, to show the logged in user next to the help button. But when I try to add the `ComboBox`, it is created as a `Tab`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon x:Name="RibbonWin" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0,0,0,113">
        <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\help.png"></RibbonButton>
        </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
        <RibbonComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test1"/>
        </RibbonComboBox>
        <RibbonTab Header="Home" KeyTip="H" Margin="0,0,0,-1" >
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="ClipboardGroup" Header="Clipboard">
                <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\paste.jpg" Label="Paste" KeyTip="V">
                    <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\paste.jpg" Header="Keep Text Only" KeyTip="T"/>
                    <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\paste.jpg" Header="Paste Special..." KeyTip="S"/>
                </RibbonMenuButton>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\cut.jpg" Label="Cut" KeyTip="X" />
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\copy.jpg" Label="Copy" KeyTip="C" />
            </RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonGroup x:Name="Questions" Header="Questions And Answers">
                <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Images\Question.jpg" Label="Questions" KeyTip="V">
                    <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\paste.jpg" Header="Add Question" KeyTip="T"/>
                    <RibbonMenuItem ImageSource="Images\paste.jpg" Header="Paste Special..." KeyTip="S"/>
                </RibbonMenuButton>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\Save.jpg" Label="Save" KeyTip="X" />
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\Add.jpg" Label="Add" KeyTip="C" />
            </RibbonGroup>
        </RibbonTab>
        <RibbonTab Header="Insert" KeyTip="I">
        </RibbonTab>
        <RibbonTab Header="PageLayout" KeyTip="L">
        </RibbonTab>
    </Ribbon>
</Grid>
```

Also is there a way to remove the the `Application Menu ComboBox` on the left that is created by default.

Answer (score 0):

Put a RibbonApplicationMenu into the ApplicationMenu-property and set its Visibility to 'Collapsed'. This will not remove the application menu, but at least it is not longer visible. There is not other way to hide it.

The ComboBox must be inserted into a RibbonTab, so a RibbonTab will be created implicitly if you do not specify anyone.

The following example demonstrates how to hide the application menu and insert a combo box:

```
<Ribbon>
    <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed"></RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>  
    <RibbonTab>
        <RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonComboBox></RibbonComboBox>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it from my friend,
this might help you
Create your own template and add it to Ribbon HelpPaneContentTempalte

```
   <Ribbon.HelpPaneContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="24">
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="btn" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Operator"/>
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn}" x:Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Bottom" 
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}" Height="120" Width="150" HorizontalOffset="-90" >
                            <Popup.Resources>
                                <Style  x:Key="LinkButton"  TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <TextBlock>
                                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Popup.Resources>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Background="White" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                                        <Image Source="Images\UserPhoto.png" Height="30"/>
                                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Operator" FontSize="16"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Operator@xxx.com" FontSize="10" Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Separator Background="LightGray"/>
                                    <StackPanel Height="30">
                                        <Button x:Name="btnAccountSettings" Content="Account Settings" Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <Separator Background="LightGray"/>
                                    <StackPanel Height="30">
                                        <Button x:Name="btnSwitchAccount" Content="Switch Account" Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property= ContentControl.Content}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </Ribbon.HelpPaneContentTemplate>

            <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <RibbonButton x:Name="btnHelp" SmallImageSource="Images\help.png" />
            </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
```